# Converting function from pecl 1 to pecl 2

Tags: php, pecl

I'm looking to move a few sites over to a new server running php55 and pecl 2. Unfortunately, pecl 2 is a massive change from the previous version and provides 0 backwards compatibility.

I'm trying to recreate the following in pecl 2 with absolutely no luck, if anyone can offer a suggestion it would be greatly appreciated.

```
$retVal = http_parse_message(http_post_fields("http://$wgserver/trusted", $params))->body;
```

Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

Took a while, but got it working this way.

```
//Set the params for posting the relevant info to the server
$params = array(
  'username' => $user,
  'target_site'=>$targetSite
);

//Create the initial request
$request = new http\Client\Request("POST","http://$wgserver/trusted");
//Add the params to the body
$request->getBody()->append (new http\QueryString($params));
//Set the client
$client = new http\Client;
//Make the POST
$client->enqueue($request)->send();
//Capture the response
$response = $client->getResponse($request);
//Extract the body of the response (since that's what I need for this example)
$bod = $response->getBody();
```